# modport ref declaration in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

My someone codes like this.

In interface file, declared as event the call_back_array, event xxxx, event yyyyyy.

```
Interface xxx
 event call_back_array,
 event xxxx,
 event yyyyyy,
...

 modport cb_bus (ref call_back_array,
                 ref xxx,
                 ref yyyy,
....
```

I can't understand what is this meaning about ref.

Answer (score 2):

SystemVerilog Interfaces have *modports* for declaring the direction of signals.

If you have just declared variables/signals in an interface and ***no*** modport is declared, then all variables/signals are taken as *ref* argument by default.

For a modport, these signals connect to input,output or inout ports of different modules.

**inout ports are to be considered as ref arguments.**

Refer [LRM 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) for more details